# How can I store my files in my website using a server?

Tags: html

I've been making a personal website of just one page to store and share my artistic content (also to make it downloadable) in a very clean way. Our laptop's free disk space is really low, so I'm wondering, is there any way to upload my files in a server for my website and make them downloadable?

I tried storing files with Google Drive but lag can even make the laptop crash and I witnessed it happens to other devices too, and I'm afraid of causing RAM issues to others. I'm used to it as when we have low disk space, RAM dies easily, but I don't want to lead others to the same thing...

The way I'm currently storing my files into my website is using laptop's disk storage, as an example:

```
<source src="files/MP3s/Utatane Piko - piano.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

I have no problems with it but the low disk space is jinxing it all...

So is there any way to use a server for my website then store the files there and get the links to play or download them?

Any help would be really appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If your site is live, you can just upload your audio files to the hosting server and link them to your page like `<source src="https://domainname.com/MP3s/Utatane Piko - piano.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`.The problem with this approach is that eventually, the storage on the hosting might get full so you have to buy bigger storage. You can also purchase a package from [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com), where you can upload your files, their system will generate a link for the file and then you can embed just the links in your page like;`<source src="https://cloudinary.com/folder_name_on_cloudinary/generated_filename.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`